# icon does not show up in iPhone 7 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have icons in Assets in different sizes (36*36 , 48*48, 72*72). when I use them, it is ok in all devices except iPhone 7 plus. It is not showing on that. and it is about just two of them.

This is what is shown on other devices(including iPhone 7 plus on simulator)

[image]

and this is on iPhone 7 plus

[image]

Note that left icon that appeared on iPhone 7 plus is same size of two others that are not showing.

Comment: is this tabbar ? or tool bar ? or custom view ?

Comment: It's tabbar and it is not showing on buttons, too. @Lion

Comment: you should show your code or storyboard setup! otherwise it is hard to identify!

Comment: there's no code. it's just setting icon in interface builder. what kind of storyboard setup do you need? @Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was about Assets. I created a new Imageset and dragged icons to that. now it is showing.